# How to measure CPU usage per site in a nginx + apache + php-fpm setup

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

If I have a server with nginx as reverse proxy and Apache + php-fpm as server. I also have a ton of websites on this server, say 200+. I want to write a script which can tell me how much CPU is used by each site at any given time.

This is important because I want to delete/disable sites overusing my server resources.

Note: every process is run by a different user.

Comment: Are your php-fpm processes splitted by different users? If yes you can do some nice things like monitoring their CPU %. Maybe this information can be added in the question.

Comment: @ValerioBozzolan yes, every process is run by a different user. Can you give me a command for that?

Answer (score 0):

If every process is executed by a different user, well done! You've made your life easier!

Your question now is: how to monitor CPU usage by user?

Some starting points:

- https://superuser.com/questions/920007/how-to-view-total-cpu-and-memory-usage-of-per-system-user-in-linux
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120570/how-can-i-monitor-cpu-usage-by-user